# Could the Old Cyrillic Djerv and Coptic Janja be related?

Tags: orthography, history

I was browsing wikipedia when I encountered the lovely letter Djerv as part of Old Cyrillic: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Djerv

Its shape is like that of an <h> with a horizontal stroke. Unfortunately, the page for Djerv doesn't go into much detail about the history of where it came from. It's also difficult to find English sources online for this sort of thing since we're normally more focused on the Latin alphabet. The wikipedia page does mention there was a spelling reform to try to resurrect the letter, but again, the sources for that are in a language outside my native tongue of English. Why was the letter lost in the first place, and why did some people find it important enough for consideration of bringing it back?

What fascinates me about this letter is the "/dʑ/" or "/tɕ/" sound that it makes and how similar it is to the "/t͡ʃ/" or "/dʒ/" sound for Janja in the Coptic script. I noticed another similarity whilst reading the wikipedia page for the Coptic Script: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coptic_script

In here, it shows how Janja came from Demotic, where the stroke is also similar to that of an <h>! I am speculating, but perhaps the diagonal line that was added for Coptic became more horizontal over time?

Comment: It doesn't look much like it to me. In any case, you'd need to show that the scholars of Preslav had knowledge of Coptic, which seems rather unlikely.

Comment: Djerv is derived from Glagolitic Ⰼ, ϫ looks to me like it's based on lowercase gamma γ. They're not very similar.

Comment: @Cairnarvon ϫ is from one of the Demotic letters for ḏ see this (sourced) table on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demotic_(Egyptian)#Uniliteral_signs_and_transliteration

Comment: I'd recommend replacing the en.m.wikipedia.org links with en.wikipedia.org ones. Both will display identically on mobile (as it will automatically redirect to the mobile page), but only the latter will display properly on desktop